# Discrete color bar: height not adjusting

Tags: graphics, color, legending

I am trying to adjust height of my color bar, but `LegendMarkerSize` is not doing what it is supposed to do.

**Code**

```
minCf = -0.6;
maxCf = -0.1;
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {minCf, maxCf}}, 9, LegendMarkerSize -> 500,       LegendLayout -> "Row"]
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {minCf, maxCf}}, 9, LegendMarkerSize -> {500, 35}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {minCf, maxCf}},    LegendMarkerSize -> {500, 35}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

The code works fine for the *continuous* color bar, but does not work for the discrete one. Below is an output I am getting.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwS9v.png)

[image]

Is there anything that I am missing?

I am running *Mathematica* on Debian 8.

Comment: This is a bug..

Comment: @Coolwater I thought so too.

Comment: @molkee I see the same effect on 10.4 and it's pretty frustrating. Would you please report it to Wolfram Support and see what they have to say about it? At least they may be able to confirm that it is a bug and not our misunderstanding. I'd appreciate it if you could report back here on what they tell you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Mathematica* 10.1 `BarLegend` is simply not written to allow the form you want.

When converted to box form `BarLegend` is handed off to one of two internal functions, `iColorGradientLegend` or `iColorBandLegend`.

`iColorGradientLegend` includes this code:

```
legendmarkersize = 
 Switch[legendmarkersize, _Scaled, 
  Switch[vorient, 
   "Horizontal", {legendmarkersize, 15}, _, {legendmarkersize, 225}], _?NumericQ, 
  Switch[vorient, 
   "Horizontal", {legendmarkersize, 15}, _, {15, legendmarkersize}], _List, 
  Switch[vorient, 
   "Horizontal", ({If[Legending`LegendDump`sizeQ[First[#1]], First[#1], 220], 
       If[Legending`LegendDump`sizeQ[Last[#1]], Last[#1], 15]} &)[
    legendmarkersize], _, ({If[Legending`LegendDump`sizeQ[First[#1]], First[#1], 
        15], If[Legending`LegendDump`sizeQ[Last[#1]], Last[#1], 225]} &)[
    legendmarkersize]], _, Switch[vorient, "Horizontal", {220, 15}, _, {15, 225}]]
```

`iColorBandLegend` uses:

```
Switch[moptLegendMarkerSize,
 _?NumericQ, vsinglemarkersize = Switch[vorient,
   "Horizontal", {moptLegendMarkerSize*Min[cnumber, 9]^(-1), 15},
   _, {15, moptLegendMarkerSize*Min[cnumber, 9]^(-1)}]; 
 cdefaultdividersizeC = {First[vsinglemarkersize], 1}; 
 cdefaultdividersizeR = {1, Last[vsinglemarkersize]};,
 {_?NumericQ | Automatic, _?NumericQ | Automatic}, 
 vsinglemarkersize = Switch[vorient,
   "Horizontal", {First[moptLegendMarkerSize]*Min[cnumber, 9]^(-1);, 15},
   _, {15, Last[moptLegendMarkerSize]*Min[cnumber, 9]^(-1)}]; 
 cdefaultdividersizeC = {First[vsinglemarkersize], 1}; 
 cdefaultdividersizeR = {1, Last[vsinglemarkersize]};,
 _ | Automatic, vsinglemarkersize = Switch[vorient,
   "Horizontal", cdefaultitemsizeR,
   _, cdefaultitemsizeC]]
```

The pattern that would match `{500, 35}` in the latter is `{_?NumericQ | Automatic, _?NumericQ | Automatic}` and in this case the code uses *either* `First[moptLegendMarkerSize]` *or* `Last[moptLegendMarkerSize]` depending on the legend orientation, but not both.